# Android: TextView acting like it's null

Tags: android, timer, textview

This is my code

```
public class GameStartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView timerTV;
Timer20 timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    timerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTV);
    timer = new Timer20(20000, 1000);
    timer.start();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_start);
}

public class Timer20 extends CountDownTimer {

    public Timer20(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timerTV.setText( "0:" + String.valueOf( millisUntilFinished / 1000 ) );
    }

}
}
```

And I get this error on the timerTV.setText...... line. :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

So when i reach this intent it crashes because of that.

Comment: How is this different from any other NPE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your views after `setContentView` in `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_start);

    timerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTV);
    timer = new Timer20(20000, 1000);
    timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize ur view in onCreate in the beginning itself.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_start);
timerTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTV);
timer = new Timer20(20000, 1000);
timer.start();
}
```